# nx migrate - Skip npm install when running nx migrate --run-migration

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am currently working on an analysis on upgrading my library and it's dependencies using [nx migrate](https://nx.dev/l/r/cli/migrate).

I have a question around nx migrate command.
I want to test the upgrade related changes directly on local rather than uploading the package to the registry again and again.

But `nx migrate --run-migrations` runs npm install before running migration.json file's scripts which updates the node_modules packages.

So is it possible to skip `npm install` which runs right after running `nx migrate --run-migrations`?

ng update has a param `--migrate-only` which I guess runs only migration scripts. (https://angular.io/cli/update).
I tried using `--migrate-only` with nx migrate, but it did not work.

Any other idea of testing upgrade related changes using nx migrate would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your migration file is already generated you could use `NX_MIGRATE_SKIP_INSTALL=true nx migrate --run-migrations=migrations.json` to run your migration and skip the npm install phase.

To create a `migrations.json` you can use this example:

```
{
  "migrations": [
    {
      "version": "1.33",
      "description": "update-1.33",
      "cli": "nx",
      "implementation": "./src/migrations/update-1.33/update-1.33",
      "package": "./dist/libs/your-path",
      "name": "update-1.33"
    }
  ]
}
```